# Getting strange and unexpected output from python while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I made a simple while loop to increase a number. And then I made a completely separate if condition to print a statement under certain circumstances. I don't understand why the two are being joined together.....

> Write a program whose input is two integers. Output the first integer
> and subsequent increments of 5 as long as the value is less than or
> equal to the second integer.
>
> Ex: If the input is:

```
-15
10
```

> the output is:

```
-15 -10 -5 0 5 10
```

> Ex: If the second integer is less than the first as in:

```
20
5
```

> the output is:

```
Second integer can't be less than the first.
```

> For coding simplicity, output a space after every integer, including
> the last.

My code:

```
''' Type your code here. '''
firstNum = int(input())
secondNum = int(input())

while firstNum <= secondNum:
    print(firstNum, end=" ")
    firstNum +=5
    


if firstNum > secondNum:
    print("Second integer can't be less than the first.")
```

> Enter program input (optional)

```
-15
10
```

> Program output displayed here

```
-15 -10 -5 0 5 10 Second integer can't be less than the first.
```

Comment: Think about what `firstNum` would be by the time you get to that if statement.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression my while loop made it so that the number is only incremented while its less than or equal to the second num. I see that's not the case now....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` loop is ensuring `firstNum > secondNum` by the time it finishes running. Then, you check to see if `firstNum > secondNum` (which it is), and your `print` statement gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
if b < a:
    print("Second integer can't be less than the first.")
else:
    while a <= b:
        print(a, end=" ")
        a = a + 5
    print("")
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer, which are not as helpful as they could be, with an explanation. Especially on old questions with existing upvoted answers

Comment: @chrslg I am very new here. I'll keep in mind.

Comment: @FarmitaFariha, please edit your answer to specify what you mean to say with some description.
You can still edit your answer any number of times after you post

Comment: @FarmitaFariha please don't just "keep it in mind"; edit the answer to add some explanation.

NB, I fixed your code. Your version missed an indent.